# How do I close a hover'ed window with LSP information, Escape does not work?

Tags: neovim, lsp

Whenever I open a hover window with my LSP plugin,

```
:lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()
```

I get a floating window hovered over text, but then I can not close it? I've tried <kbd>ESC</kbd> and the like. How do you close these hovered windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do **NOT** focus (click inside) of the hover, closing it is as simple as using any navigation key (<kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>). However, if you do  click inside, you'll either have to focus outside again or use `:q`.

Comment: How can I remap <esc> to close the hover ?

Comment: @gruvw I've also tried everything but the kitchen sink and still can't figure it out.

Comment: @gruvw @ProXicT I wouldn't remap `<Esc>`, but see my answer for a way to remap some single key to close the window.

Answer (score 2):

Improving [Telemachus' answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/43436) further, if you want to toggle the hover with `K`, you can do the following:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("LspAttach", {
    callback = function(ev)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "K", function()
            local base_win_id = vim.api.nvim_get_current_win()
            local windows = vim.api.nvim_tabpage_list_wins(0)
            for _, win_id in ipairs(windows) do
                if win_id ~= base_win_id then
                    local win_cfg = vim.api.nvim_win_get_config(win_id)
                    if win_cfg.relative == "win" and win_cfg.win == base_win_id then
                        vim.api.nvim_win_close(win_id, {})
                        return
                    end
                end
            end
            vim.lsp.buf.hover()
        end, { remap = false, silent = true, buffer = ev.buf, desc = "Toggle hover" })
        -- Probably lots of other keymaps...
    end
})
```

Comment: This is neat, but I'll mention one thing: it steps on the default secondary function of `K` with the LSP. By default, if you open a window with `K` and then enter `K` again, the cursor will move into the window opened by the first `K`. As I mention in my answer, this can be useful if the documentation window is long and you want to move around through it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and Google sent me here. I was disappointed by the accepted answer, so here's what I came up with after a little research.

First, the situation as I understand it:

- If you call `vim.lsp.buf.hover` twice, you will jump into the window. (This can be useful if you want to read further into a long piece of documentation.) If `vim.lsp.buf.hover` is mapped to `K` in normal mode, as it often is, then `KK` will jump you into the window.
- Once you are in the window, you can easily close it with `q`. (You don't even need `:q`, though that works too.)
- As the OP says in their answer, if you are **not** in the hover window, and you do any movement, the window will automatically close. That's fine, but annoying if you don't want to move the cursor.
- One simple answer is to map something to `hl` (or `jk`). That will move the cursor back and forth one character (or one line) but (usually) leave the character where you started. However, this can cause small annoyances if you open a hover window when you are on the first column (or the last line if you use `jk`). In those cases, the cursor will move since the first movement won't do anything and the second will over correct.

After being annoyed about all of this, I came up with the following.

```lua
local hover_close = function(base_win_id)
    local windows = vim.api.nvim_tabpage_list_wins(0)
    for _, win_id in ipairs(windows) do
        if win_id ~= base_win_id then
            local win_cfg = vim.api.nvim_win_get_config(win_id)
            if win_cfg.relative == "win" and win_cfg.win == base_win_id then
                vim.api.nvim_win_close(win_id, {})
                break
            end
        end
    end
end

-- Later, or in another file, when you create keymaps for LSP
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("LspAttach", {
    callback = function(ev)
        local keymap_opts = { remap = false, silent = true, buffer = ev.buf }
        -- Probably lots of other keymaps, but the relevant two...
        vim.keymap.set("n", "K", lsp.buf.hover, keymap_opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<Leader>;", function()
            hover_close(vim.api.nvim_get_current_win())
        end, keymap_opts)
    end,
})
```